# Cannot access XAML element from C++ code. WinUI 3 (WinUI project templates)

Tags: c++, xaml, winui, winui-3

I am learning with some small projects and I don't know, how to access XAML element from C++ code.
Can you help me please?
It says "cannot determine which instance of overloaded function is intended",
screenshot: https://pasteboard.co/JjjKCAT.png

Thank you
Lukas

Comment: Are you using C++ with the WinRT template library?

Comment: It's using WinUI project templates.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/winui/winui3/

Comment: That documentation for WinUI says that only C# and C++/WinRT (which is shorthand for C++ with the WinRT template library) is supported.  C++/CX (which is a different programming language from C++, which had been derived from C++) is not supported.  Is your code C++ (using WinRT) or C++/CX?

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++ using WinRT.  I'm familiar with C# using WPF and XAML.  I was hoping I could point you to suitable documentation, but it appears you are already looking at the suitable documentation.  There may be another StackOverflow member is is familiar with WinUI that will chime in.

Comment: Thak you for your answer. It's C++ (using WinRT).

Comment: @Bluekas You need to call `ProgressRing1()` to retrieve its value.

Answer (score 0):

When creating something in XAML, it creates two methods with the same name, one that returns that object and takes 0 arguments, and one that returns nothing (aka a void) and takes one element of that type. In your case, if you want to retrieve the value, you need to the following:

```cpp
void MainWindow::Button_Click_Ring(...)
{
    // Get the ProgressRing:
    const auto progressRing = ProgressRing1();

    // Set the ProgressRing:
    ProgressRing1(newValue /* the new value */);
}
```